# Cross Apply Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I have a query where I think it would be more efficient to use cross apply.  I've changed the syntax from join to cross apply, but I'm getting a generic syntax error:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Line 14: Incorrect syntax near 'apply'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

This is the first time I'm using cross apply, and I don't see a syntax error (at least when comparing to examples I've found).  Here is the code:

```
Select v.PC_ID
, v.PC_Name
, v.LOB
, v.REG
, v.DST
, v.PC
, d.Effective_Date as DateOfLastInc
, p.TotalPriceIncPct
, p.last_update_by
, d.PlanEffective_Date
, p2.PlanTotalPriceIncPct
--INTO #temp1
from v_PC_Profile v
cross apply (
    Select pc_id
, Effective_Date=max(Effective_Date)
, PlanEffective_Date=max(PlanEffective_Date) 
from dbo.Price_Inc_PC_Details
where pc_id = v.pc_id
group by pc_id
) as d --on d.PC_ID=v.PC_ID
left join dbo.Calendar c on c.FULL_DATE=d.Effective_Date 
left join dbo.Price_Inc_PC_Details p on d.PC_ID=p.PC_ID and d.Effective_Date=p.Effective_Date
left join dbo.Price_Inc_PC_Details p2 on d.PC_ID=p2.PC_ID and         d.PlanEffective_Date=p2.PlanEffective_Date --added by ajl 1/15/2013

WHERE segment NOT IN ('Closed', 'Overhead')
and segment not like '%closed%'
and Close_Date is NULL

group by v.PC_ID
, v.PC_Name
, v.PC
, d.Effective_Date
, p.TotalPriceIncPct
, d.PlanEffective_Date
, p2.PlanTotalPriceIncPct
, v.REG
, v.DST
, v.LOB
, p.last_update_by
, p.PlanEffective_Date
, p.PlanTotalPriceIncPct
order by v.PC_ID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

SD

Comment: try to remove the `as` ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `CROSS JOIN`? I assumed `CROSS APPLY` was for functions.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Nope, you can use cross apply for queries.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is very handy for things like aliasing calculations.

Comment: As written your syntax looks correct (parses for me in SSMS).  What version of SQL are you using, I'm assuming SQL Server?

Comment: Syntax looks fine to me, and works in [this simplified SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abb72/1). You should remove `pc_id` from both the select list and the group by within the cross apply though to reap the full benefits (note the simpler plan in the second query on the SQL Fiddle).

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO . . . You can think of `cross apply` with queries as a way of putting correlated subqueries in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 9):

It used to be that a database with compatibility level of 80 (a.k.a SQL Server 2000) in a later version of SQL Server gave this error for UDFs.

The syntax looks OK and parses OK on my SQL Server 2012.
I've created a database on a SQL Server 2008 R2 with compatibilitylevel 80 but it *also* parses OK.

See ["Using APPLY"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on MSDN

> To use APPLY, the database compatibility level must be at least 90.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it's on SQL Server 2000.  I didn't know we had any older than 2005.  Thanks so much to all!

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the sub-query after cross apply operator, the order of 'group by' and 'where' should be inter-changed:

```
(
Select pc_id
, Effective_Date=max(Effective_Date)
, PlanEffective_Date=max(PlanEffective_Date) 
from dbo.Price_Inc_PC_Details
group by pc_id
having pc_id = v.pc_id
) as d
```

Please try it and see if it resolves your issue given that this does not change the results you want to achieve.

Additionally,  the group by at the fag end of the query seems to serve the purpose of "DISTINCT".